# My laptop does not support ultrawide monitor?

Tags: display, hdmi, external-display

I got a Dell Vostro 3500 with i7 11th gen and Iris Xe Graphics from work, I have my personal monitor, a LG 29WK600 Ultrawide 2560x1080 monitor.

While trying to connect it with the laptop, it only accepts 16:9 resolutions... After some research I found some articles saying it's a hardware limitation, saying it's HDMI 1.4 that only accepts 1920x1080@60hz... so the display quality is very bad...

Has anyone else faced something similar? Is there some way to bypass this? Like a adapter, driver, etc to achieve the 21:9 resolution?

Just can't get how a brand new laptop nowadays still have some stupid limitation like this...

https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/pt-br/000126548/resolution-on-external-monitor-limited-to-1920-x-1080-using-hdmi?lang=en

Comment: An adapter won’t eliminate a limitation of HDMI

Comment: I said that because i saw something about displaylink's adapters which has a special chipset and blabla, but too sad there's no escape from this issue :(

Comment: Even if you converted a HDMI signal to DisplayPort you would be limited by the limitations of HDMI 1.4

Comment: I dont think the problem is the aspect ratio, I think its the bandwidth of the hdmi Interface.

Comment: As per https://www.dell.com/community/Vostro/Refresh-rate-stuck-on-30-hz-external-Dell-monitor/td-p/7880210 you should be able to get the resolution you want out of HDMI **but only at 30Hz.  I had a much older Dell laptop that would drive 4k, but only at 30 Hz** and expect this issue is the same for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a physical limitation of the HDMI video port as detailed here: https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-hr/vostro-15-3500-laptop/vostro_3500_setup_specs/ports-and-connectors?guid=guid-da941dbf-7209-45b3-a380-f529efb39077&lang=en-us

However, I also note that it comes with an optional USB C port and USB 3.2 port which provides plenty of opportunity to purchase an external dock or video adapter with capabilities that will work with your monitor.